# Deploy api gateway with terraform based on a swagger file

Tags: swagger, aws-api-gateway, terraform

I want to deploy my api gateway with terraform using a swagger file to describe my api. The swagger.yaml looks like this:

```
swagger: '2.0'
info:
  version: '1.0'
  title: "CodingTips"
schemes:
  - https
paths:
  "/api":
    get:
      description: "Get coding tips"
      produces:
        - application/json
      x-amazon-apigateway-integration: ${apiIntegration}
      responses:
        '200':
          description: "Codingtips were successfully requested"
```

Terraform is giving me a `BadRequestException` saying that `The REST API doesn't contain any methods`.

Because of this I am thinking that it is trying to deploy the REST api without waiting for the methods and integrations of this api to be created.

This made me think in the direction of having to add `DEPENDS_ON` to the `aws_api_gateway_deployment`. However I do not know what to depend on since I don't define the method and integration resource using swagger. They should be automatically deducted from the swagger definition.

Am I thinking in the right direction and if so, what do I have to make my `aws_api_gateway_deployment` depend on? Or is something else wrong with the way I am trying to deploy this api.

My `apigateway.tf` file looks like this:

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_rest_api" "codingtips-api-gateway" {
  name        = "ServerlessExample"
  description = "Terraform Serverless Application Example"
  body        = "${data.template_file.codingtips_api_swagger.rendered}"
}

locals{
  "get_codingtips_arn" = "${aws_lambda_function.get-tips-lambda.invoke_arn}"

  "x-amazon-coding-tips-apigateway-integration" = <<EOF
#
uri = "${local.get_codingtips_arn}"
passthroughBehavior: when_no_match
httpMethod: POST
type: aws_proxy
credentials: "${aws_iam_role.api_gateway_role.arn}"
EOF
}

data "template_file" codingtips_api_swagger{
  template = "${file("./swagger.yaml")}"

  vars {
    apiIntegration = "${indent(8, local.x-amazon-coding-tips-apigateway-integration)}"
  }
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_deployment" "codingtips-api-gateway-deployment" {
  rest_api_id = "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.codingtips-api-gateway.id}"
  stage_name  = "test"
}
```

How can I fix the `BadRequestException: The REST API doesn't contain any methods` ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I found out what was wrong. It is a syntactical error in the `locals{}` block.
`uri =` should be `uri:` . Using a colon instead of an equal sign. The block then looks like this:

```
locals{
  "get_codingtips_arn" = "${aws_lambda_function.get-tips-lambda.invoke_arn}"

  "x-amazon-codingtips-get-apigateway-integration" = <<EOF
# comment for new line
uri: "${aws_lambda_function.get-tips-lambda.invoke_arn}"
passthroughBehavior: when_no_match
httpMethod: POST
type: aws_proxy
EOF
}
```

Researching this I found that it reads easier when you specify the `x-amazon-apigateway-integration` in the swagger.yaml like this:

```
swagger: '2.0'
info:
  version: '1.0'
  title: "CodingTips"
schemes:
  - https
paths:
  "/api":
    get:
      description: "Get coding tips"
      produces:
        - application/json
      responses:
        '200':
          description: "The codingtips request was successful."
      x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
        uri: ${uri_arn}
        passthroughBehavior: "when_no_match"
        httpMethod: "POST"
        type: "aws_proxy"
```

The `data{}` and `locals{}` blocks in your terraform then look like:

```
data "template_file" codingtips_api_swagger{
  template = "${file("swagger.yaml")}"

  vars {
    uri_arn = "${local.get_codingtips_arn}"
  }
}

locals {
  "get_codingtips_arn" = "${aws_lambda_function.get-tips-lambda.invoke_arn}"
}
```

Comment: Hi, how're you converting your swagger representation in terraform one?

Comment: I have an example here: https://ordina-jworks.github.io/cloud/2019/01/14/Infrastructure-as-code-with-terraform-and-aws-serverless.html#api-gateway

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I can't find how you convert swagger api gw into terraform in the link you sent? Can you show me please?

Comment: @smarber He is not converting at all.  He's showing how to load the swagger file directly (into the body param of aws_api_gateway_rest_api).  Unfortunately, with this approach, the complete api interface is coupled to the API Gateway instance, such that you can't modularize the terraform.