# Deploy api gateway with lambda using terraform based on a swagger file

Tags: lambda, aws-api-gateway, openapi

([Deploy api gateway with terraform based on a swagger file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54047171/deploy-api-gateway-with-terraform-based-on-a-swagger-file))

I have same problem as above but not able to integrate with lambda.
Also i followed your step but i still see : creating API Gateway Deployment: BadRequestException: No integration defined for method

I have added following in openapi/swagger yaml file.

```
x-amazon-apigateway-integration: 
uri: ${uri_arn} 
passthroughBehavior: "when_no_match" 
httpMethod: "POST" 
type: "aws_proxy"
```

And if we have multiple paths do we have to add this integration for every endpoint paths? how do we add this in yaml file when there are bunch of paths? manually adding is not possible as there will be bunch of endpoints.